# How can I print out the int values from the array?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

The code below shows my progress, but I cannot print the numbers that were entered. I don't know where to put `println("you entered the following numbers")` in the loop so that it'll show up when the loop stops.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class aufgabe5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How much numbers do you want to enter?");
        x = input.nextInt();
        int j = 1;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numbers = new int[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the " + j++ + ". number:");
            numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();

        }
        System.out.println("You entered following numbers");
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: so i have to print out the array i...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-an-array)

Comment: Just loop back from 0 to numbers.length on your array, calling System.out.println(x) each time.

Comment: hmm the problem is when a user enters for example 2 numbers 2 and 5...this 2 numbers will be saved in the numbers[i] array. i don't know how i can get acess tho this array... to print it out where the "sout "x" " is now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `x` like

```
System.out.println(x);
```

to [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

**Edit**

To print the array reversed,

```
String str = Arrays.toString(numbers).replace(", ", " ,");
str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
System.out.println(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().insert(0, "[")
            .append("]"));
```

Comment: is there also a code to print the arrays reveresed?

Comment: @Saboteur Not as easy as `Arrays.toString()` but edited.

Answer (score 0):

Intialize the String before the loop, then keep adding the values to it.
After the loop finishes you can print the whole thing.

```
String someVar="You entered following numbers: ";
for(int 1=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
    someVar=someVar+numbers[i]+",";
}
System.out.println(someVar);
```

Comment: Although the code seems pretty clear, it's good form to add a bit of explanatory text to an answer like this.